# PHP shell_exec() won't execute screen command to run .jar file

Tags: java, php, shell, ubuntu, shell-exec

I am working on a minecraft control panel in Ubuntu and thus I need to start/stop a .jar filewith shell_exec();

When I try commands like "whoami", the output is normal. But when I try this:

```
shell_exec("screen -dmS mcsrv java -Xmx512M -jar /var/www/srv/craftbukkit.jar -o true nogui");
```

It does not do anything, I have checked the permissions too and www-data is the owner of the files

Comment: btw: wouldn't it be easier to start the minecraft server like all the other services/daemons under ubuntu as described at http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Dedizierter_Minecraft-Server (in german, but google translate does an OK job there, it starts with "To improve the handling of the server...") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to redirect the standard error stream to stdout (by appending `2>&1` to the command), fetch that output and print it to check whether there was a meaningful error message

```
$cmd = "screen -dmS mcsrv java -Xmx512M -jar /var/www/srv/craftbukkit.jar -o true nogui";
$redirect = '2>&1';
// using variable substitution only for readability here 
shell_exec("$cmd $redirect", $output);
var_dump($output);
```