# PHP shell_exec with screen and Ts3Musicbot

Tags: php, linux, shell-exec

i am working on a Webinterface for some [Ts3Musicbots](https://ts3musicbot.net/) and i have one Problem with starting the screen.

My code: ( [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754443/php-shell-exec-wont-execute-screen-command-to-run-jar-file) )

```
$cmd = "screen -d -m -L $botverzeichnis /mb/$botverzeichnis/start.sh -account $botacc -secretkey $secretKey -port $botport -webif-pw $adminpw -webif-pw-user $userpw -max-disk-space 100 -noquery"; 
$redirect = '2>&1';
// using variable substitution only for readability here 
shell_exec("$cmd $redirect", $output);
```

And it dosen't start. When I print out $cmd and put it into Putty it works!

The directory whith the Start scrippt is at the moment in var/www/

Please Help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, shell_exec returns the output and only has one parameter. It should be:

```
$cmd = "screen -d -m -L $botverzeichnis /mb/$botverzeichnis/start.sh -account $botacc -secretkey $secretKey -port $botport -webif-pw $adminpw -webif-pw-user $userpw -max-disk-space 100 -noquery"; 
$redirect = '2>&1';
// using variable substitution only for readability here 
$output = shell_exec("$cmd $redirect");
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: and when i dont need the output?

Comment: if you don't need the output you don't need to assign it to a variable, but you need to explain more. What are you doing, how are you doing it, what error messages do you get, etc.

Comment: I try to start a java process (TS3Musicbot) in a screen. and the output from the shell_exec is NULL

Comment: Well, if I'm not mistaken, the output from `shell_exec` for screen should be `NULL` if the command worked...

Comment: But I don't see the screen and an Webinterface must shown on my url:2001